# Is it possible to exploit relation among divisors in the computation of multivariate residues?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, residue-calculus

Let's consider the definition of residues as in pag. 650 of Griffiths & Harris.
Suppose we have a differential form that can locally be written as:

$\omega = \frac{h(z)}{f_1(z) ... f_n(z)} dz$

the functions $f$ locally define divisors $D_i$.

Now, suppose I know that $D_1$ is linearly (and/or homologically, I do not know if the two concept coincides) equivalent to another divisor $D'_1$, easier to treat. For I may not be able to solve $f_1 = 0$ but I know explicitly $D'_1$.

May question is: it is possible to use this information to simplify the computation of a local and/or global residues of the above form?

I was thinking of considering

$\omega' = \frac{h(z)}{f_1(z) f'_1(z) ... f_n(z)} dz,$

write its divisor as $(D_1 + D'_1 ) + D_2 + ... + D_n$ and apply the global residue theorem to say that the global residue of $\omega$ and of

$\omega'' =  \frac{h(z)}{f'_1(z) ... f_n(z)} dz,$

coincide, or something similar. Any suggestion?